# Case insensitive search using ALTER SESSION on ODP.NET/EF connections?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I've got some EF/LINQ statements that I need to be case-insensitive text searches, but our oracle database is case sensitive.  How can I execute the necessary ALTER SESSION statement at the connection/command level so that it will affect the subsequent same-context calls?

Command I think I need to run ([OTN Thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2132321?tstart=0))

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI
```

I'm aware of both [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and [Database.Connection.CreateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as methods, but I can't figure out the 'when'.  If I manually try to do this to the context after creation but before the LINQ, I have to manually open & close the connection, and then it seems to be a different transaction as the LINQ, and doesn't seem to be applying.

Comment: Will [ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) not work for you?

Comment: Good question, I've added info about that & what I've tried so far

Comment: Also, not Oracle, but a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Comment: Good suggestion, but does not appear to be working in EF5/ODP.NET.  Tried `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`, `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, and `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Comment: Here are a couple of kludgy ideas to inject extra SQL into a Linq-to-SQL query:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409210/how-to-intercept-and-modify-sql-query-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: Which EF version are you in?

Comment: Any chance you could upgrade to 6? You could use its command interceptor API.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option as ODP.NET does not support code first EF6 yet...

Comment: Have you also set alter session set nls_comp=LINGUISTIC ? Because otherwise your sort-parameter may be ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is not a solution to your question of how to inject `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI` into a query, but it may help you with your insensitive case search, just use `.ToLower()` .

Comment: This did work.  For some reason I had it in my head that .ToLower() was not usable on LINQ2Entities part of the query (materialized view etc..).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first option would be to ask the DBA to add a "login trigger" to the DB account you are using.  The disadvantage there is two fold: One it will be set for every command, and two the DBA will laugh at you for not simply doing the oracle defacto "upper" on everything.

These guys seemed to pull it off using the ExecuteStoreCommand off of the context. I'm not a fan of EF so I can't help much here, but I'd guess you'd need to execute your linq query inside of that same context?
http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2012/07/31/ef4-part-10-database-agnostic-linq-to-entities-part-2.aspx

You may be able to use one of the "executing" methods in the command interception feature in EF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464#BuildingBlocks

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have permission to make login triggers or other permanent adjustments

Comment: It's also unclear from the example you linked where & when the ExecuteStoreCommand should be executed to affect the subsequent LINQ command.